# Design and program in Glade and Python a scrollable list of a bunch of elements

Tags: python, linux, gtk, glade

I'm a "new" programmer, more that 15 years ago I learned python. Now.. I completely out!

I started again to program in python (on linux), and I want to create a "simple" timer.

The main interface consist in two section, one to set the timer, and the other one, in a list of the started timer, in this case we have multiple timer started.

This "list" isn't a simple gtktree, but each item of the list, consist in a "mini window" with the time left, and some button, to stop, pause etc... (instead of creating a new window for each timer started)

I'm doing this mainly for learning (and in second time, I have a timer for my kitchen!). The timer is only an excuse. I only want to lean of create a scrollable list of "mini window".

Is this feasible in glade? How I can interact with python whit the multiple timer in the list? Can you tell me something that I can go and look for on, the internet or in some documentation?

Very thanks in advance!

I have tried to search on similar list, but I found only result about tree list or similar one. (I currently search about made this in multiple separate window, instead of a list, but I'm still in learning mode)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Currently there is NO code, I only ask how to proceed with this approach and if it is possible to do it, if so I can also do the research on my own, but I would need some suggestions on what to look for, my searches were in vain

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all, Glade only works with **GTK3**, I recommend you start with **GTK4**, which has a very interesting interface creation tool called **WorkBench**. But let's consider what you want to do regardless of the version.

There are many ways to achieve the visual result you want, but what you want seems to be:

a **Gtk.Window** with a **Gtk.Pained** as a child. As the first child of **Gtk.Pained** (the one on the left), you'll have a **Gtk.Box** containing all the widgets you need to create your timer. For example a **Gtk.Entry** to put the timer time, and a **Gtk.Button** to save the created timer.

As the second child of **Gtk.Pained** (which will be on the right side) you will have a **Gtk.ListBox**, inside it you will have a **Gtk.ListBoxRow** as a child for each timer already created.

Each **Gtk.ListBoxRow** will have a **Gtk.Box** as a child, and as children of **Gtk.Box** you will have a **Gkt.Label** (to display the time, like 04:20:12), and a **Gtk.Button** for play/pause .

This is quite simple to do in Glade.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote you, but **thanks**! I am **definitely** considering your kind advice about **GTK4** and **WorkBench**! I have to study a lot, because your description is ok (I can't find Gtk.ListBoxRow in glade!), but I have to do some research for handling all this in python! Again, many thanks!